# Tkinter: Bind <Enter> event to entire window (but not all widgets)

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to bind an Event to the window. For example I want a function called when the mouse pointer enters the window. The code below does this but sadly the function is also called whenever the mouse pointer enters the Button. I tried `B.unbind("<Enter>")` but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def function(event):
    print("Hello World")

B = tk.Button(root, text ="Label")

root.bind("<Enter>",function)
root.geometry("100x100")
B.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried actually calling `bind` on the widget?

Comment: No because I do not want the event to bound to the Button, I want it to only be bound to the Background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make this work is to check for `event.widget` and see if it is the root window, which is a instance of `Tk`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def function(event):
    if isinstance(event.widget,tk.Tk): #check if event widget is Tk root window
        print("Hello World")

B = tk.Button(root, text ="Label")

root.bind("<Enter>",function)
root.geometry("100x100")
B.pack()

root.mainloop()
```